# order by method is not working on queryset

Tags: django

order by  not working on queryset  no working at all and i dont know where is the mistake seems everything is okay !

views.py

```
class PostDetailView(DetailView):
model = Post
template_name = 'detail.html'
#context_object_name = 'post'
#form_class = CommentForm

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    post_comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=self.get_object()).order_by('-date_added')
    data['comments'] = post_comments

    if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
        data['comment_form'] = CommentForm(instance=self.request.user)
    return data

def post(self, request, slug, *args, **kwargs):
    new_comment = Comment(comment=request.POST.get('comment'),
                            name = self.request.user,
                            post = self.get_object())
    new_comment.save()
    return redirect('core:detail', slug=slug)
```

models.py

```
class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
name = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
comment = models.TextField()
date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.comment
```

Comment: How/where is the order by not working? In a template?

Comment: post_comments = Comment.objects.filter(post=self.get_object()).order_by('-date_added') in template yeah

Comment: How do you know it's not ordered correctly? Where are you displaying the results? If in a template can you share the relevant section of the template and a selection of results that are not ordered correctly?